# How to save data online from all users using your app in android

Tags: android, datastore

I want to ask a question from my app users and get their answers but i don't know how to collect those data.
Please help me I need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a form inside your application. And, ask users to fill that form. The forms needs to be connected to an database server. You may use 000webhost.com (free) to create your database. Just populate the table in database from the user response. 
For this follow the following procedure:

1. Create a online database (000webhost.com)

2. Write php code to insert data into the database form and save that php on the file manager on server.

3. From android create a async task to execute that php.

4. Pass your parameter or user response as request attributes while executing the php. 

5. php will save user's response on your server.

 Now you can access that database from anywhere.

Note: This may require an internet connection in application.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is much vague.

In general, app need to use HTTP POST with some standard data format as JSON/XML for communication between web server/client app.

This way client apps send/receive data in portable format across platforms &
implements UI/functionality as per platform standard e.g. Android or iOS

Answer (score 0):

You could implement Google analytics in your app. Raise an event when you ask a question.